# Solving eqn. of the form K = AGL + BGT, where A,B,L,T are invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am obtaining the following equation in a regression problem:
\begin{eqnarray}
Z'_1Y_1\Omega^{-1}_{1}A+Z'_2Y_2\Omega^{-1}_{2}A = Z_{1}'Z_1\Pi A'\Omega^{-1}_1A + Z_{2}'Z_2\Pi A'\Omega^{-1}_2A
\end{eqnarray}
and would like to solve it for $\Pi$.  Now, let's define the matrices: $Z_i$ is $n_i \times k$, so that $Z_i'Z_i$ is invertible. $Y_i$ is $n_i \times (1+p)$ and $\Omega_i$ is $(1+p) \times (1+p)$ and $A$ is $(1+p) \times p$, where $i \in \{1,2\}$. For invertibility, we assume $Z_i'Z_i$ and $A'\Omega^{-1}_iA$ to be invertible.

I would really appreciate your help, perhaps also a reference on how to get started.

This comes from a likelihood function that I am maximizing and I believe the solution should look similar to this: $\Pi = (Z'Z)^{-1} Z' Y \Omega^{-1} A (A' \Omega^{-1} A)^{-1}$.

I am not sure how I can 'free' the parameter $\Pi$ adequately, because multiplying with inverses of say $Z_i'Z_i$, would eliminate the matrix in front of one occurrence of $\Pi$ but not the other one.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Another idea I am having is to write the RHS as a partitioned matrix.

Comment: Who voted this down and why? Is there something wrong with that question?

Comment: Consider $\Pi$ to be one long $n^2$ vector and solve using the usual $Ax=b$ sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat but I don't quite understand what you mean? How do I group the terms around $\Pi$ together? It's a k by p matrix, also. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well if you use the basis $E_{ij} = e_i^T e_j$ $i=1,...,k$, $j=1,...,p$ you can write the equations in terms of an unknown $x \in \mathbb{R}^{kp}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @copper.hat but I am still not sure I understand what you mean. Should I write the $\Pi$ as a vectorized version, i.e. $vec (\Pi)$ and stack the equations somehow? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood. Are you trying to find a numerical solution or are you looking for a closed form expression for a solution? I was answering the former.

Comment: Thank you for checking back @copper.hat I was looking for a closed form solution. I believe the form of the solution will look like what I wrote it will look similar to, given the high degree of symmetry. I was trying to reorganize the equation into matrix form but I don't see a quick way, yet. I have also tried to 'engineer' a solution by mimicking the closed form expression for a related problem (where we have no subscripts). Thanks so much!

Comment: A neat re-write that highlights the symmetric structure is this: $L_1 + L_2 = M_{11} \Pi O_1 + M_{22} \Pi O_2$ and I am suspecting the solution to be something like $\Pi = M^{-1} L O^{-1}$ or rather a sum of terms to eliminate pesky cross-terms.

Comment: The problem can be written as a Sylvester equation ($AX+BX = C$), it not clear to me that a nice solution exists. To guarantee invertibility, you need the spectrums of $(Z_1'Z_1)^{-1} (Z_2' Z_2)$ and $-A'\Omega_1^{-1} A (A' \Omega_2^{-1} A)^{-1}$ to have no overlap.

Comment: Thanks so much @copper.hat but I believe there is a typo in the Sylvester equation. I didn't even know they existed. Where can I find more references in this? It seems there is so much lin. alg. I don't know - argh.

Comment: The control theory literature, Riccati equations, Lyapunov equations maybe?

Comment: Thank you so much @copper.hat. Indeed I was constantly puzzled by the fact that my physics/undergraduate linear algebra curriculum proved insufficient in so many cases in statistics and engineering and it appears as though large swathes of lin. alg. have moved away from pure math to their continued development in the service of applied disciplines, such as CS your field or the social sciences (mine). Yes, I will work on this using control theory as it arises in optimization.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff out there, its impossible to keep abreast of everything...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answer is not essential because copper.hat did the job ; yet this will can be better in writing it.

Your equation can be rewritten in this sylvester equation $UX+XV=C$ where $U=(Z_1^TZ_1)^{-1}Z_2^TZ_2,V=A^T\Omega_1^{-1}A(A^T\Omega_2^{-1}A)^{-1}$ ; that is $WX=C$ where $W=U\otimes I+I\otimes V^T$ if we stack matrix in vector row by row. cf.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

If $spectrum(U)=(\lambda_i)_i,spectrum(V)=(\mu_j)_j$, then $Spectrum(W)=(\lambda_i+\mu_j)_{i,j}$. Thus, if for every $i,j$, $\lambda_i+\lambda_j\not=0$, then $W$ is invertible and $X=W^{-1}C$. Clearly, there is no closed form for the solution (except if $U=V$) ; then you search a numerical solution. Beware, if you invert directly $W$, then the complexity is in $O(n^6)$ ; in fact there is a method in $O(n^3)$.cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation